# Running production scalable websocket server library in golang

Tags: go, websocket, horizontal-scaling

We are trying to build a scalable socket server in golang. We need a library that supports the following

1. Must be horizontally scalable.
2. Must be a low latency backend which also optimises memory usage.
3. Support for pub sub notifications in addition to push notifications.

Or is nodejs-socketio / golang-socketio the best alternative?

Answer (score 1):

As I understood your question u want to build scalable and flexible WebSocket,
I strongly recommend Go gorilla framework which can find out [here](https://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/websocket)

and also u can handle up to 3 million online connections which u can find out 
[here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/million-websockets-and-go-cc58418460bb/).

Addition u can use [Redis](https://redis.io/download) for more speed and [gRPC](https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/go/) for more flexibilities.

Hope this can help